# Как перемещаться между Контроллерами в Swift

Tags: swift

пишу на Swift шестой день, поэтому не знаю насколько вопрос актуален для общественности, но для меня - да.

Приложение под IOS создаю через storyboard, поэтому все переходы у меня осуществляются посредством *зажатый ctrl+перетягивание открытия на нужный view*. В приложении есть четыре "ветви":

1. Авторизация+Аутентификация ( Начинается с NavigationController )
2. Личный кабинет пользователя ( Начинается с TabBarController )
3. Личный кабинет Администратора ( Начинается с TabBarController )
4. Личный кабинет Сотрудника ( Начинается с TabBarController )

StoryBoard Entry Point у меня стоит на первой ветви.

Вопрос: как перенаправлять не с помощью storyboard, а через программный код? Я искал в интернете, но везде код обычно занимает больше 10 строк, я в это не верю... И везде перенаправление идет с помощью ViewController, но мне же надо перенаправлять на NavigationController или TabBarController в зависимости от того - авторизирован ли пользователь.
Пожалуйста, объясните максимально доходчиво ( как 3-х летнему ребенку ), как это сделать?

Comment: Код приложите для примера как "везде" сделано

Comment: @shmidt9, если это сделано из storyboard, то прикладывать скрины или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот через Навигэйшн контроллер:

```
if let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as? NewViewController {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Вот просто открытие нового контроллера:

```
if let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as? NewViewController {
    newViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // это значение можно менять для разных видов анимации появления
    newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // убрав или закомментировав эту строку, вы получите появление смахиваемого контроллера
    present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Через ТабБар, кодом не подскажу, так как сам не делал, но уверен, что ищется в пять секунд.

P.S. Еще, извиняюсь, для всего этого, нужно указать в сториборде идентификатор контроллера (то, что у меня в коде выше "NewViewController")
Вот тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо! И в правду работает!

Comment: Я рад, что у вас получилось!